# Base64 decode from Buffer to Buffer efficiently in node (node.js)

Tags: javascript, c++, encoding, node.js

I currently have a python and C version of wsproxy (WebSockets to plain TCP socket proxy) in [noVNC](http://github.com/kanaka/noVNC). I would like to create a version of wsproxy using node.js. A key factor (and the reason I'm not just using existing node WebSocket code) is that until the WebSocket standard has binary encoding, all traffic between wsproxy and the browser/client must be encoded (and base64 decode/encode is fast and easy in the browser).

Buffer types have base64 encoding support but this is from a Buffer to a string and vice versa. **How can I base64 encode/decode between two buffers without having to convert to a string first?**

Constraints:

- Direct **Buffer to Buffer** (unless you can show Buffer->string->Buffer is just as fast).
- Since node has built-in base64 support I would like to use that and **not external modules**.
- In place encode/decode within a single Buffer is acceptable.

[Here](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/dd236d9f4b2db1e9) is a discussion of base64 support in node, but from what I can see doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Wasn't the only problem with this that the flash fall back was becoming horrible slow? Otherwise binary just works fine, although there's the UTF-8 encode/decode overhead in the protocol, but that's always there. Anyways, `buffer.copy` doesn't apply encoding when copying and using `toString()` is 150x slower in a quick test. You may want to file a bug on Node for buffer copying which copies in the specified encoding.

Comment: Since WebSockets data is currently limited to UTF-8 (hopefully this will change in future revisions), the proxy has to do some sort of encoding of the raw socket data. The flash fall back adds the twist that you can't send a zero byte (which technically is legit UTF-8). Encoding each byte to UTF-8 takes 150% the space (any other UTF-8 encoding would be too slow to decode in Javascript). Base64 is 133% so it's more efficient in both space and processing.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using streams, but first read through this [blog about UTF-8 decoding](http://debuggable.com/posts/streaming-utf-8-with-node-js:4bf28e8b-a290-432f-a222-11c1cbdd56cb) because you will likely encounter similar issues. I'm not suggesting that you do UTF-8 encode/decode if you don't need it, but that you look at how this code handled the issue of a single character spread across multiple bytes that were separated by a chunk boundary.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear enough in the question that for speed sake I'm not wanting Javascript implementation (for which code exists) but a native Base64 decode routine. I already have a way of using native base64 routines but they traverse through a string first and I am wanting to get rid of that.

Comment: If you want C++ code, then why not take existing Base64 encode/decode code and use that to build your extension. By the way, the tags were not very clear so I deleted a couple and added a couple. This may get you more answers.